# Hola, alguien me podría explicar que quiere decir " un diagrama de bloques del firmware/software"?

Tags: arduino, hardware, sensor

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad donde tenemos que usar Arduino Uno y varios sensores para leer algunos parámetros como aceleración, distancia, etc.
El mentor me ha dicho que no hace falta hacer una simulación que funcione perfectamente, basta con hacer un diagrama del firmware/software explicando cómo la placa lee los sensores, el orden, etc.
No entiendo muy bien cómo se hacen estos diagramas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Un diagrama de bloques del hardware muestra la conexión de los componentes:

[image: Hardware]

Y este diagrama de bloques del software resume la operación de un controlador PID:

[image: Controlador PID]

El objetivo es mostrar en una sola imagen la operación del sistema, descartando los detalles. Este diagrama me dice que la entrada es la velocidad/posición del motor, la que pasa por tres módulos (proporcional, integral y derivativo), cuyas salidas se suman para determinar la velocidad del motor.

También hay una señal desde el controlador que me dice la velocidad/posición actual del motor, y que se usa como retroalimentación negativa de la velocidad/posición deseada.

Comment: Muchas gracias!